# Why is test --help not working?

Tags: bash, 22.04, coreutils

My Ubuntu is working good.

```
$ lsb_release -a
LSB Version:    core-11.1.0ubuntu4-noarch:printing-11.1.0ubuntu4-noarch:security-11.1.0ubuntu4-noarch
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS
Release:    22.04
Codename:   jammy
```

When I try built-in bash `test` command :

```
test --version
test --help
```

I see no output.

What works :

- `man test` gives a man page ( GNU coreutils 8.32  )
- `info test|more`
- `test -1 -gt -2 && echo yes`

It shows

```
TEST(1)                          User Commands                         TEST(1)

NAME
       test - check file types and compare values

SYNOPSIS
       test EXPRESSION
       test
       [ EXPRESSION ]
       [ ]
       [ OPTION

DESCRIPTION
       Exit with the status determined by EXPRESSION.

       --help display this help and exit

       --version
```

that

```
test --version
```

should work.

Where is the problem?

Comment: If you want to see documentation for the bash builtin `test`, use `help test` or `man bash`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question asks about *"built-in bash test command"* but the `man` and `info` pages you are quoting are those for the external `/usr/bin/test` command provided by the `coreutils` package.

The `--help` and `--version` options only apply if you explicitly invoke the **non-builtin** test program, and only when you invoke it as `[` not `test`, as documented in the `info` extract:

> If EXPRESSION is omitted, ‘test’ returns false.  If EXPRESSION is a
> single argument, ‘test’ returns false if the argument is null and true
> otherwise.  The argument can be any string, including strings like
> ‘-d’, ‘-1’, ‘--’, ‘--help’, and ‘--version’ that most other programs
> would treat as options.  To get help and version information, invoke
> the commands ‘[ --help’ and ‘[ --version’, without the usual closing
> brackets.

Ex.

```
$ /usr/bin/[ --version
[ (GNU coreutils) 8.32
Copyright (C) 2020 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <https://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>.
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Written by Kevin Braunsdorf and Matthew Bradburn.
```

Comment: which test gives /usr/bin/test

Comment: @Adam the `which` command ignores shell builtins - in `bash`, use `type test` (or `type -a test` for an ordered list) instead. See for example [Why not use "which"? What to use then?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/85249/why-not-use-which-what-to-use-then)

Comment: How can  explicitly invoke the builtin test program?

Comment: @Adam if you just type `test` in the bash shell, you will get the builtin version (provided you haven't overridden `test` with an alias or shell function of your own). The `COMMAND EXECUTION` section of `man bash` explains more fully.

Comment: @Adam also, the builtin tool has no `--help` option. To see the help/manual of a builtin, you run `help` and the builtin's name. In your case, you want `help test`.